# Unforseen errors when running sudo npm install -g @vue/cli

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js, terminal, vuejs2

I've tried every solution on the web, besides he dangerous silver bullet `chown -R` solution to get `vue.js` up and running via the `cli`.

Supposedly, I don't have permission to manipulate the `npm` folder, but again I'm not too sure anymore.

In `Terminal`, I'm getting the error below.  I've google searched the errors one by one, tried out some potential solutions but nothing worked.

What can I do to fix this?

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@11.3.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64' 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf/node" "/usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf/node /usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf/node" "/usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf/node /usr/local/jamf/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
npm WARN @apollographql/apollo-upload-server@5.0.3 requires a peer of graphql@^0.13.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ @vue/cli@3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chown -R` option. Because the folders it's trying to access were made by another proces, your user account is not the owner, and thus can't make changes there. When you use `chown -R` you just change the ownership of the folder to your user, not dangerous. I had to do it a couple of times for npm on my new laptop.

the command you would want to use is:

`sudo chown <username> -R ./*`

In folder: `/usr/local/jamf/bin/lib` i think, if that doesn't work, try going up one folder and use the same command there.

Comment: Hey mika, may you recommend the exact `chown -R` command please?  Maybe you might know something different the previous plethora of commands I've tried.  Also, is npm accessibility the problem I'm facing?

Comment: I added the exact command you need to use. And well your user account doesn't own the folder it's trying to change, and so the OS doesn't let you do it, even with sudo. So it's no necessarily npm, just your OS. So far I haven't seen this sort of issue on windows, but i have on Linux and MacOs.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work.  I entered my machine username with and without the `<>` but I get error that says: `chown: -R: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in the command, the * tells it to match all files and folders

Comment: I got rid of the * but I'm still getting the same error.  I even went up 1 folder and used the same command, but still getting the same error :(.

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error.  This is extremely strange.

Comment: Does your account have admin rights on your system?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm
```

See this [vue-cli issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3402)